# How to slice a list of strings till index of matched string depending on if-else condition

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have a list of strings =

```
['after','second','shot','take','note','of','the','temp']
```

I want to strip all strings after the appearance of 'note'.
It should return

```
['after','second','shot','take']
```

There are also lists which does not have the flag word 'note'.

So in case of a list of strings =

```
['after','second','shot','take','of','the','temp']
```

it should return the list as it is.
How to do that in a fast way? I have to repeat the same thing with many lists with unequal length.

```
 tokens = [tokens[:tokens.index(v)] if v == 'note' else v for v in tokens]
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of an iteration when you can slice list:

```
strings[:strings.index('note')+1]
```

where `s` is your input list of strings. The end slice is exclusive, hence a `+1` makes sure `'note'` is part.

In case of missing data (`'note'`):

```
try:
    final_lst = strings[:strings.index('note')+1]
except ValueError:
    final_lst = strings
```

Comment: I edited my question. This will only work if the flagged word is present in the list. How to implement an if-else condition as well?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make sure the flagged word is present:

```
    if 'note' in lst:
        lst = lst[:lst.index('note')+1]
```

Pretty much the same as @Austin's answer above.